# Is it possible to query Files by their URL in django?

Tags: python, django, file, django-models, django-queryset

If I have a model MyImages consisting of a FileField, is there a way I could query it by URL of the File? I know Django allows something like:

```
my_image.file.url
```

but I wasn't sure if URL is query-able in a FileField. Thank you!

Comment: You mean you want to find a file by its URL?

Comment: yes, (a file that's part of a model)

Comment: There is no builtin way, you would have to loop through your objects and check the url individually. Obviously not ideal for large sets of objects. So consider a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an url field inside your model and override the save method to set it to file.url, so you can query your model by this url.

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
    url=models.CharField(...) 


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = self.image.url
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then you make url field hidden in the form
(Set editable=False on the model field. As a result, any form created from the model via ModelForm will not include that field. [More info here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form))